# What is $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{3n+2} \right) ?$

Tags: limits

> What is $$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{3n+2} \right) ?$$

My attempt: 
\begin{align}
\log \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{3n+2} \right) &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log \left( \frac{3n+1}{3n+2} \right)
\end{align}
How to move on?

https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/files/week6.pdf (8)

Comment: Use a comparison test to show that the series diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{3n+2}\right)=-\frac{1}{3n+2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$
you can see the sum of first term is $-\infty$ and the second one is finite. Hence, the sum is $-\infty$. Returning to the product, you will have $0$.